# How do I upgrade from Windows 7 RC to Windows 7 RTM?

Tags: windows-7

I want to install Windows 7 RC.  I know about the time bomb in June of 2010, where it will cease to work, and that a few months before that it will shut down every two hours.

If I install Windows 7 RC, will I be able to upgrade it to a non-time bombed version?  If I pre-order the RTM, will I need to wipe clean and do a fresh install when it is released?

---

**UPDATE:**

I installed Windows 7 RTM on my wife's laptop, upgrading from Vista Ultimate x64 with no problems.  Had to uninstall Daemon Tools & ATI Catalyst Control Center first though.  I decided not to install the RC first, since I have access to the Technet download on Aug 6.

Comment: Awesome that this question was mentioned on the StackOverflow podcast, sorry my answer is the official MS standpoint and not the good work around Joel linked to.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Brandon LeBlanc on this Windows 7 Team [blog post](http://windowsteamblog.com/blogs/windows7/archive/2009/07/13/update-on-windows-7-rtm.aspx) states you need to do clean install from the RC versions.

[Brandon](http://www.brandonleblanc.com/) is the Windows Communications Manager at Microsoft

Comment: in that blog post, Brandon says they expect the RTM in the latter half of July.  I think I'll just wait for the RTM version.

Comment: The offiical release date for Windows 7 is October 22. The RTM in July is for MSDN and TechNet subscribers.

Comment: I've personally done this on my laptop and it went just fine. It takes longer than a "clean" install, but afterwards all my stuff was there, and it all worked. That's what I cared about, so I was very pleased.

Comment: Upgrades from RC to RTM are _not_ supported.  You may get lucky.

Comment: You can actually tweak a file to make the upgrade work. See PhantomTypist's answer below for an illustrated guide, otherwise Joel's link is roughly the same thing.

Answer (score 32):

There is a technique described [here](http://blogs.zdnet.com/Bott/?p=922&page=5) which sounds like it might work to upgrade RC->RTM. Has anybody tried this?

Comment: I used it successfully to upgrade from the last beta to the RC, so i'm certainly gonna try... once i have access to the RTM version.

Comment: FWIW, i tried it... for now at least, it appears to have worked just fine.

Comment: It worked in my machine

Comment: It works on my 3 machines.

Comment: It worked for me upgrading from build 7200. Yay!

Answer (score 15):

The How-To Geek has a write-up on exactly how to perform an upgrade from RC to RTM.

[How to Upgrade the Windows 7 RC to RTM (Final Release) :: the How-To Geek](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/3075/how-to-upgrade-the-windows-7-rc-to-rtm/)

EDIT: FYI, in the linked article the How-To Geek explains exactly what build number you must specify in the cversion.ini file to make this way of upgrading work.

Comment: The same technique was also linked in a couple of answers above, though I went for the walk-through approach to make it easy to understand.

Comment: Yeah, thank you for doing that. I was unsure about the needed MinClient build number needed.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, but there's a catch.  The "upgrade" is really a custom install that will leave your current Windows 7 RC install intact.

> However, you will not be able to do an
>   upgrade installation, in which your
>   existing programs and data are left in
>   place. Instead, you'll have to do what
>   Microsoft calls a custom installation.
>   This is essentially a clean install,
>   but your existing operating system,
>   programs and data are squirreled away
>   in a folder labeled WINDOWS.OLD. You
>   end up with a fresh Windows 7 setup,
>   but you can access that folder to get
>   to any needed data. (Sorry, the
>   programs in there won't work - you'll
>   need to reinstall them.)

Here's the [full article](http://blogs.chron.com/techblog/archives/2009/07/a_major_windows_7_upgrade_question_gets_an_an.html).

Comment: Note this is not the case when you use the method of editing CVersion.ini. All my programs and data were preserved and ready to go.

Answer (score 4):

Here is how:

1. Download the RTM ISO.
2. Copy that burnt image to a temp folder
3. Find the `Sources` directory in the temp folder, and open the file `CVersion.ini` in your favorite text editor
4. Modify the `MinClient` option to 7000 (from 7233.0)
5. Save the file, and then run setup as normal to start installation.

[image: Works in my machine]

Original from [LifeHacker](http://www.lifehacker.com.au/2009/04/microsoft-wants-windows-7-testers-to-downgrade-to-vista/)
Slightly modified to match the exact steps I take to do it.

**Note:** This is essentially the same as Joel's answer
**More:** Super complete guide with pictures at [HowToGeek.com](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/3075/how-to-upgrade-the-windows-7-rc-to-rtm/)

### Important Notice

The Windows 7 beta or RC releases were Ultimate edition, so you’ll only be able to upgrade to the RTM (final) if you are installing Ultimate Edition. (from HowToGeek.com)

Comment: This is essentially the same as joel's answer, just copied localy

Comment: @Andrew: you are right. Added note to the post

Comment: the 'important notice' part can be avoided with registry tweaking like described here for vista: http://dltv.wordpress.com/2007/05/30/upgrading-windows-vista-enterprise-to-windows-vista-ultimate/

i've done upgrade from RC ultimate to RTM enterprise using this technique, i can confirm it works

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be working per [Sam Gentile](http://samgentile.com/Web/windows7/upgraded-windows-7-from-rc-to-rtm/) using [technique described here](http://blogs.msdn.com/e7/archive/2009/04/07/delivering-a-quality-upgrade-experience.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and no. You can keep your existing install, but it will be moved to a Windows.old folder.

See [Engadget](http://www.engadget.com/2009/07/14/microsoft-confirms-windows-7-rc-upgrade-rules/):

> Users running an activated version of Windows 7 Release Candidate will not have to "reinstall an older version of Windows before using a Windows 7 upgrade disk." Unfortunately, those who choose this path will see all of their files and such ushered into a folder labeled "Windows.old" when the final version of Win7 is installed

Comment: Right - you won't have to wipe your computer clean, but you will have to do a fresh install (your old install will, as joshunt said, be saved in "Windows.old").

Answer (score 1):

[See this FAQ by Ed Bott](http://blogs.zdnet.com/Bott/?p=1184)

Answer (score 1):

When my copy of the Beta expired, it started BSODing with an expiration reason.  Now *that's* an effective way to enforce it :)

Answer (score -1):

GA isn't until October 22, not the latter half of July.

The current rumor is that you will in fact be able to upgrade, however until the final product ships there's no way to be sure.

Upgrading may simply be as easy as editing one config file on the DVD ([instructions](http://blogs.zdnet.com/Bott/?p=922&page=5)), then installing from there.  I did it from the Beta to the RC without issue.

Comment: I have access to Technet, so I'm able to download RTM even as I type this.

Comment: **Public release** isn't until October 22, 2009.  The **RTM** has already happened.  MSDN and Technet subscribers got it August 6, 2009.  OEMs got it even earlier (within the last week or three).

Comment: -1 for wrong RTM date

Comment: Correct, I meant GA isn't until October 22.  RTM happened already.