# I'm using a Windows 7 v. 7100 RC, can I upgrade?

Tags: windows-7, windows, license

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Upgrading from Windows 7 RC to Windows 7 RTM](https://superuser.com/questions/1298/upgrading-from-windows-7-rc-to-windows-7-rtm)

I'm using a Windows 7 copy I won from a conference about two weeks ago. It was an official Microsoft conference.

I'm absolutely loving this OS and wouldn't mind laying down 150$ for the license once it releases fully.

My only problem lies in the installation.

I really don't want to re-format my laptop again, and copy my data, etc.

So will I able to just pop in the original purchased license I'll eventually get, and have everything upgrade online?

Comment: Duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/1298/upgrading-from-windows-7-rc-to-windows-7-rtm

Comment: BTW, go to that question, look for Joel Spolsky's answer, and follow the link he mentions.

Comment: You "Won" a copy of the RC? The RC is a free download. Also two weeks ago the RTM (final version) was available. Are you sure you didn't win a copy of the RTM?

Comment: Ray, the RTM is not yet available for the general public.

Comment: It's not available to the general public, but it is out there. A lot of people already have valid licences for Windows 7 RTM; I have one through the Academic Alliance program.

Comment: I know it's not available to the general public. But it sure is available for Microsoft to give away. I'm using it now from MSDN.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**How to upgrade Windows 7 RC to RTM**

Step 1: Just to be safe, you will probably want to back up your data (but you already knew that).

Step 2: Download the desired Windows 7 RTM ISO or have your upgrade disc handy. Make sure this is the same architecture as your current install as you cannot go from 32-bit to 64-bit, or vice-versa. You must upgrade to the same version.

Step 3: Mount the ISO using something like Daemon Tools, or extract it with your favorite ISO extracting tool (WinRAR, for example). Or, if you have the upgrade disc, make sure it’s in the drive.

Step 4: Open up the disc so you can see all the contents of it. In Computer, you will need to right click and select “Open” to avoid opening Autoplay instead.

Step 5: Copy all the contents of the disk (all files) to a new folder somewhere on your computer. I copied everything to a 4GB flash drive I have because I am upgrading multiple PCs.

Step 6: Open your new folder (or flash drive) with the contents you copied over from the Windows 7 install disc, and navigate to the Sources directory, and look for a file called cversion.ini.

Step 7: Open the file so you can edit  it (I use WordPad). Make the following change:

```
[HostBuild]
MinClient=7233.0
MinServer=7100.0
```

Change it to:

```
[HostBuild]
MinClient=7000.0
MinServer=7100.0
```

Step 8: You’re done! You can run setup.exe directly from the folder without loading it on any media. Setup copies the files on to a temporary folder on your hard drive so it can complete the upgrade. Or if you have media or a USB drive,  burn or copy the contents of the folder to the disc/media and run setup.exe directly from it.

Setup will now give you the option to upgrade your existing installation.

[Source](http://www.therobpage.com/blog/?p=235)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can via registry hacks, however I wouldn't.

Whilst upgrading Windows has got a lot better in recent years, I don't want to test it or think anyone should use it on anything other than a RTM / final product.