# Windows 7 RC upgrade to Windows 7 Home Premium?

Tags: windows-7, upgrade

Does the hack to make Windows 7 RC upgradeable also work for the retail release of Windows 7 Home Premium, since RC is Ultimate?

I need to be absolutely sure this works before I decide to buy the student discount.

Comment: Duplicate of about a million questions, but mainly this one: http://superuser.com/questions/1298/upgrading-from-windows-7-rc-to-windows-7-rtm

Comment: One thing about most of the solutions in that question is they actually don't answer his, since they talk about going from RC Ultimate->Retail Ultimate, rather than to Home Premium which requires additional modifications.

Answer (score 1):

It should work, but you'll need to change the product type in your Windows RC registry to Home Premium.  Go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\Current Version` and change the value of *ProductName* and *EditionID* to Home Premium rather than Ultimate.

Overall instructions for the upgrade [here](http://www.gmtaz.com/index.php/how-to-upgrade-windows-7-rc-ultimate-to-rtm-enterprise/), except they are for upgrading to Enterprise; just replace Enterprise with Home Premium in the instructions.  I was able to use this method to upgrade from RC to Enterprise on my workstation at the office.  One thing to note is that my upgrade took way, WAY longer than the clean install I did at home.

Also, a correction: `winclient` in the instructions should be `minclient`.